# how to copy the value of a field in create () odoo 10

Tags: python, function, odoo

I am on Odoo 10 and I want to retrieve the value of a field in a function create to copy it when I perform this function. Here is my code:

```
@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self, vals):
    vals = {'test': "Test numéro 1", 'test2': 'Test numéro 2'}
    res = self.env['test.test'].create(vals)

    return vals
```

Example: I want to get the previous value from the  field and add it to the new value.
How to do ? Thank you

```
@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self, vals):
    vals = {'test': "what to put here?", 'test2': 'Test numéro 2'}
    res = self.env['test.test'].create(vals)

    return vals
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. You want to create new object when button is clicked? What do you want to achive?

Comment: Sorry, I'm french. In fact, I want to duplicate the value of a field